# Get the latest XML file from a HTTPS

Tags: python, https, beautifulsoup, request

I have a series of XML files at a HTTPS URL below. I need to get the latest XML file from the URL.

I tried to modify this piece of code but does not work. Please help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests

url = 'https://www.oasis.oati.com/cgi-bin/webplus.dll?script=/woa/woa-planned-outages-report.html&Provider=MISO'
response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
#html = urllib.request.urlopen(url,verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
```

I suppose beautifulsoup does not read response object. And if I use the urlopen function, it throws SSL error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` does not understand the `requests`'s `Response` instances directly - grab `.content` and pass it to the "soup" to parse:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")  # you can also use "lxml" or "html5lib" instead of "html.parser"
```

`BeautifulSoup` understands the "file-like" objects as well - which means that, once you figure out your SSL error issue you can do:

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not frame my question correctly in the first place. But after furthering researching, I found out that I was really trying to extract all the URLs within the referenced url  tags. With some more background of the Beautiful Soup, I would use soup.find_all('a').